# RabbitMQ - backup using storage snapshots

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a system of several services running together on a single host that I want to backup using LVM snapshotting (or similar).
One of the services is **RabbitMQ**.
Since RabbitMQ's messages might be in memory and never get to disk, I'd like a way to flush them to disk before backing up, and maybe lock the service for the snapshot to run.
Is this a reasonable scenario? Does RabbitMQ support such a flow?

I'm aware of the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), but this does not go with the strategy of snapshotting the same "point in time" for the whole system...
I saw many discussions, but none that refer to the storage snapshotting.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to backup is to stop the rabbitmq applications using `rabbitmq stop_app`.

but if you are using `not persistent` messages when  you stop RMQ you lose the messages.

if you need to backup the messages you should use always persistent messages and also the lazy queues for an huge number of messages, then `stop_app` and backup.

In this way you flush all the messages to the disk and you can backup the `mnesia` dir.

In my personal opinion, does not make sense backup the RMQ messages, I'd use the mirroring queues instead of backup.